# jQuery .data method (sorta) not working in plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a tooltip plugin for jQuery, and I'd like to use the .data method to check if a tooltip has already been opened for the attached object. Right now I'm getting the following error out of the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'data'

Here is a paste of my plugin: http://pastebin.com/nsrBCb2Y

If I use the exact example from the jQuery website it works (the $('body').data() one) but it seems like using this.data() causes problems. Does anyone know if you can use the .data method on 'this' in a plugin? Or even better if anyone know why this doesn't work, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: I think in most cases where you're using `this` it should actually be `$(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cases of

```
this.data('opened')
```

should be

```
$(this).data('opened')
```

Inside of the live bound event handler, `this` refers to the DOM node, not a jquery collection containing the dom node.